# i want to use asgi2 version application in python

Tags: python, asgi

Most applications in Python are using ASGI version 3.
For example, in django, asgi supports asgi version 3. How can I use asgi2 version?

Even if it's not django
Are there any applications that use asgi2, and if so, which ones?

Comment: Why would you want to use a previous version? The spec was bumped because there were improvements on it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am developing a python monitoring application and wanted to make it compatible with the asgi2 version as well.

Answer (score 0):

i solve this problem.
In Django, it seems that the asgi application is only compatible with asgi version 3.

So I checked to see if I could use asgi2 in other web applications in Python. I tried using asgi2 in a flask with uvicorn.
We used uvicorn to run the flask application and lowered the ASGI version to 2. it worked fine

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).